# Wordpress Hook after blog activation

Tags: php, wordpress, wpmu

I am new to WordPress,

Is there a hook that will trigger during a blog activation. I am working on a multisite, then I noticed that after the user registers, they have to activate their blog by clicking a link that was sent to their email.

I want to have a hook that after blog activation, I will get the blog's meta then store it in the user's meta.

Is this possible? I have been searched on the internet but can't find an example of a hint.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old.
But by the help of the plugin [Simply Show Hooks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simply-show-hooks/) i got to know
that I can use

```
 add_filter("wpmu_activate_blog","something")
  function something($user_id){

   //do the crazy stuff
   //for example with 
   // $blog_id = get_user_meta($user_id, "primary_blog", true);
   //get_blog_option and get_user_meta 
   //and the correspondening update options thingys


  }
```